# Does the field has to satisfy both conditions to be a conservative field or just either 1st or 2nd?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, conservative-field

For the field to be a conservative field, does the field have to satisfy the both conditions?

1. Work done is independent of path followed by the body.
2. Work done in a closed path is zero.

Comment: 1 & 2 are equivalent. Can you see why?

Answer (score 0):

These two conditions are in fact equivalent. Since the work does not depend on the path, by solving the integrals you get $W_{ab} = V(b) - V(a)$ where $V$ is the potential and $a$ and $b$ are initial and final points, respectively. If the path is closed, then $a=b$ and hence $W = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For a force field to be conservative you need to show that the work done (by the field, or against the field, depending on your convention) is **always** independent of the path taken. You can show this by demonstrating that $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times F = \boldsymbol{0}$ (provided that the domain is simply connected) or by showing that $\boldsymbol{F}$ is the gradient of another scalar field.

It is not equivalent to saying that work done in **a** closed path is zero. Maybe if you show that it is zero for **any** closed path it is equivalent.

Comment: In fact, $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = 0$ does not imply $\oint_C \mathbf{F} d\mathbf{r} = 0$ for every closed curve C.

Comment: You are right, for some reason I assumed a double implication between irrotational and conservative. Is it possible that there exist a double implication in simple cases? I'll check and edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: I believe that if you stick only to simply connected regions, the implication holds.